# After using maven to generate a struts2-archetype-blank project, I get a build error

Tags: maven, struts2, archetypes

I am using Eclipse, M2E plugin, Maven3 for web devlopment.

I am trying to create basic struts2 project using their struts2-archetype-blank:

```
mvn archetype:generate -B -DgroupId=tutorial \
  -DartifactId=tutorial \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.struts \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=struts2-archetype-blank \
  -DarchetypeVersion=2.3.4
```

So i am getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project GetVsPostTest: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /code/tutorial/src/test/java/tutorial/example/ConfigTest.java:[65,28] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : method addConfigurationProvider(com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider)
[ERROR] location: class com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager
```

On this line in ConfigTest.java:

```
configurationManager.addConfigurationProvider(c);
```

[image]
Can somebody tell me whats going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please tell me whats wrong

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Maven?

Comment: the struts dependency is correct? does the jar in eclipse in libraries show the correct version?

Comment: I got this example using 
mvn archetype:generate -B  -DgroupId=tutorial -DartifactId=tutorial -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.struts -DarchetypeArtifactId=struts2-archetype-blank -DarchetypeVersion=2.3.4

Comment: them imported to eclipse

Comment: Cut-and-paste some errors into the question - your image (which I assume is a screenshot) doesn't display on my machine.

Comment: protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        XmlConfigurationProvider c = new XmlConfigurationProvider("struts.xml");
        configurationManager.addConfigurationProvider(c);
        configurationManager.reload();
    }

This is method where error coming 
The method addConfigurationProvider(XmlConfigurationProvider) is undefined for the type configurationManager
& this object is from com.opensymphony.xwork2.XWorkTestCase.configurationManager

Answer (score 0):

There looks to be a bug in the struts2-archetype-blank for 2.3.3 and 2.3.4 at least. You can change this line in ConfigTest.java:

```
configurationManager.addConfigurationProvider(c);
```

to this:

```
configurationManager.addContainerProvider( c );
```

and it should work.

FYI - I've submitted a bug for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3864